# Bind a data frame only if a value on a certain column is not a duplicate

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe as follows:

```
df_1

id     value     value_2
1      1.1545    hello
2      185.11    foo
8      135415    bar
```

I want to bind it with this

```
df_2

id     value     value_2
3      0.0455    ahh
4      0.11      ehh
1      0.44      ihh
```

the third row must not get binded since there is id 1 in the df_1.

So it should be

```
id     value     value_2
1      1.1545    hello
2      185.11    foo
8      135415    bar
3      0.0455    ahh
4      0.11      ehh
```

Comment: So based on the example, is it the first one?

Comment: Is it only regarding the `id` column?

Comment: yes. only id column. if it exists already, i keep the first one

Comment: Well.... you just totally changed your question. `rbind` and then remove with `duplicated`?

Comment: Yes. I just want to combine two data frames but do not insert rows from the second one if it has a similar id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by either placing the datasets in a `list` and then `rbind` it with `rbindlist` from `data.table`, and select only the rows with 'id' that are not duplicated.  If there are `duplicated` 'id's, the first 'id' row will be kept and the other ones will be deleted.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df_1, df_2))[!duplicated(id)]
```

A variant of the above is using `unique`

```
unique(rbindlist(list(df_1, df_2)), by = 'id')
```

---

Or

```
rbind(df_1,df_2[!df_2$id %in% df_1$id,])
```

Comment: yes both works! any suggestion w/c of the two I should use?

Comment: @MolenFernando  The first one should be faster (not tested)